# Markov chain question

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Consider an irreducible, recurrent Markov Chain ($X_n$) on a countable state space $S$ with transition probability $p(x,y).$ Pick a sigma-algebra $A \subset S$ and let $T_k=\inf\{n>T_{k-1}:X_n \in A\}$, with $T_0=0$, be the time of the $k$-th return time to $A$. (All $T_k<\infty$ by recurrence.) Define $Z_n=X_{T_n}$ for $n \geq 0$. Prove that, for $X$ started from any $x \in A$, $Z_n$ is a Markov chain on $A$ with a transition probability $Q$. Determine $Q$ and prove that $Z_n$ is irreducible and recurrent. 
Any help would be welcomed.

So basically we want to prove that $P^{\mu}(X_{T_{n+1}}=x|X_{T_{n}},X_{T_{n-1}},\ldots)=P^{\mu}(X_{T_{n+1}}=x|X_{T_{n}})$. 
I tried to use the Strong Markov Property, namely $P^{\mu}(1_B \circ\theta^{T_n}|F_{T_n})=P^{X_{T_n}}(B)$, I think this is the key, but I do not know how. I do not have any ideas on how to relate $P$ to $Q$. Any hints would be sufficient. Thank you.

Comment: Frank Zermelo: the question is "on hold".  Could you edit it to let us know your thoughts on the question and what you have tried? That will help people write answers that are more useful to you.

Comment: I wrote some thoughts on the problem. Not much, as I do not see a clear path to approach it.